# Tell JSHint to ignore object variable names like obj.@var

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jshint

I have an application that consumes a JSON web service produced by IBM Domino.  Several of the members in each object have variable names that begin with an @ symbol, like obj.@unid for example.  This causes JSHint to thrown an error saying 'Unexpected @'.  Is there an option that would turn this off?

Comment: is obj['@unid'] acceptable instead of obj.@unid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think an object's property names can contain an "@" symbol and *not be encapsulated* with quotes (just like other characters, such as "-", "+", "^", etc.).

These are all invalid:

```
// Invalid: SyntaxError
var obj = { @uid:123 };
console.log(obj.@uid);

// Perfectly valid
var obj = { "@uid":123 };
console.log(obj["@uid"]);
```

It sounds like your json webservice is not returning valid JSON in the first place by not encapsulating the names with quotes.

***Now, to answer your JSHint issue*** (and, for others that stumble upon this for JSHint). The list of options are here: http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/ but I don't think anything will help you for this specific case.

According to the docs (http://www.jshint.com/docs/) you can hide explicit warnings by running your file with the `--verbose` option and adding the specific error code to the `/* jshint */` options. For instance, if the following triggered:

```
$ jshint --verbose myfile.js
myfile.js: line 6, col 3, Unnecessary directive "use strict". (W034)
```

You could add that warning code to hide it:

```
/* jshint -W034 */
```

Unfortunately, your variable naming is not a warning, but an error (`E024`) and those "E" error codes cannot be suppressed so the above example would not work for you in this case.

Comment: Thanks.  The JSON returned actually looks like your second example of {"@unid":123}, so using the obj["@unid"] notation worked for me :)